# Order by localized enum

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core

Is there any best practice for ordering data by localized `enum` in `ef core`?

My entity has an `enum` which can be translated into many languages, but when the user wants to order data by an `enum` I need to order it by the localized string not by the index.

I don't want to use any client evaluation. I can not use value conversion because I need to support more languages.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Use a lookup table with the localized names. How do you localize those names now?

Comment: How many values does the enum have? How many rows are you ordering? Are you returning all ordered rows or limiting by Skip/Take ? Can the translation be put into the database, or is it only available during runtime?

Comment: Another question would be required performance, which is what row count question. As I can't imagine a scenario that would be fast on significant amount of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup table instead of trying to force the sort order, with the enum value as ID and extra fields for the language code and translation. If you cover the translation and language code with an index, you can get fast sorting and filtering by the translated value.

Enums are a client *language* concept, meant to change infrequently. In the database, lists of values are stored in tables though. Enum values will appear as magic values unless you store them in their own tables.

Once you find you need to perform data operations (like sorting) on non-value properties like names, or you find that the number of values changes too frequently, you need to start treating enums as relational entities too.

That doesn't mean they need to surface as *ORM entities* in your DbContext, unless it's a DbContext meant for translation management :

- You could use different contexts for querying and editing. Localized sorting is typically used for reporting queries. Displaying stuff in a grid is a reporting query too. In these cases you could map your entity to a localized view that joins the main tables with the lookup tables and allows filtering and sorting by language.
- You could use [raw queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to map to a function or raw query that returns the lookup name, and add extra LINQ operators to it.
- You could use [EF Core Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#interception-of-database-operations) to add the lookup logic to the query, although that's more complex than using different contexts.

If you plan to support many languages though, you should think about a proper localization design for data that's stored in the database.